# How to know that it is a new month?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I want to know **when** is the **New Month**. So that I can do some operation 
like, copy last month data [eg. Category.Title] from last month [Jan] to the new month [Feb].

```
Month  Catagory
=====  ========

Jan => Category.Title 
Feb => New Category.Tile (copy based on Jan's data)
```

How do I construct the logic to detect that Today is a new month (so that I can preform the copy operation)?

Basically, I want to detect **when** is the **New Month begin**?

Comment: This question is incredibly ambiguous. Is this checked once a day? Where is this checked? Flex app? Database? Return from database?

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question, because it sounds like you're asking how to test whether today is the first day of the month...

Comment: @SamDeHaan i wanted to know/detect that Today is a new month

Comment: @jimw no, not the 1st day of the month but when is a new month begin

Comment: We don't know what you want. There has to be **more context**. How are you looking at the date? When are you looking at the date? Do you want this to change to the new month at exactly 01\xx\xxxx at 00:00:00.000? Saying "I want to know that today is a new month" is **not** enough for us to help you.

Comment: @SamDeHaan I have some Catagory.Title in Jan month and when comes Feb, I what to be able to copy the Catagory.Title to Feb. So, I'm looking for the begin of Feb (or end of Jan) and when comes Feb my program will perform the copy operation. Or is there a better way to achieve the above result. thanks.

Comment: If I am going to help you, you need to tell me **more**, not try to reword the **same information**.

Comment: @SamDeHaan ok ask me what you want to know, thanks

Comment: I've already asked eight questions you haven't answered. Do you want to check this when a user opens a flex app? Do you want this to happen inside a database? Checking when a new month starts is *easy*. `((new Date()).date == 1)`. Doing it in context can be a lot harder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10194/discussion-between-jameslcs-and-sam-dehaan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the logic to check if today is the first day in a month, you can use the following code.

```
var d:Date = new Date();
if (d.date == 1) {
    //today is the first day in a month
}
```

Depending on where/when you're doing this however, it may not have the effect you desire. Without more information, I can't really help you there.

Answer (score 0):

You should employ this fabulous logic found on the provided link and go from there. Pretty much you need to find out if current date of the month. Lets say if today is the 15th of April, you will then need to find out how many days are there in April, 2012, and where does the 15th of April fall. And then have a counter count the remaining days until the new month (May) begins. You also want to make sure that you are checking for the leap year. This link also has a function that checks for the leap year. I am giving you a high level idea to go about getting what you trying to.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-days-in-month/

Thanks a lot.